# bash cut columns to one file and save onto the end of another file

Tags: linux, bash, paste, cut

I would like to cut two columns from one file and stick them on the end of a second file.  The two file have the exact same number of lines

```
file1.txt
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

file2.txt
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h i  j
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h i  j
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h i  j
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h i  j
```

So far I have been using

```
cut -f9-10 file2.txt  | paste file1.txt - > file3.txt
```

which outputs exactly what I want

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  i  j
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  i  j
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  i  j
```

However I don't want to have to make a new file I would prefer to alter file 1 to the above.  I've tried

```
cut -f9-10 file2.txt  | paste file1.txt -
```

but it simply prints everything on screen.  Is there a way of just adding columns 9 and 10 to the end of file1.txt?

Comment: note you mention the two files have the same amount of lines, whereas the 2nd has one more.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sponge` from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/)! It allows you to `soak up standard input and write to a file`. That is, to replace a file in-place after a pipe.

```
cut -f9-10 file2.txt  | paste file1.txt - | sponge file1.txt
```

Note you can also do what you are doing by using `paste` with a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst).

```
$ paste -d' ' file1.txt <(awk '{print $(NF-1), $NF}' file2.txt) | sponge file1.txt
$ cat file1.txt
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 i j
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 i j
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 i j
```

This joins `file1.txt` with two last columns from `file2.txt` using `' '` as delimiter.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the one I posted, so I removed mine and up-voted this one.

Comment: Thanks @MikeAtkins :) I did some research and found out about this `sponge` thingy. It looks like the tool!