# How to use paste to append one column from file2 to file1

Tags: bash, paste, cut

Similar to

[Append one column from fileB onto end of FileA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686519/append-one-column-from-fileb-onto-end-of-filea?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [bash cut columns to one file and save onto the end of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927999/bash-cut-columns-to-one-file-and-save-onto-the-end-of-another-file)

However, the methods presented by the answers to the questions above do not seem to work with my files on my machine. See the `paste` errors below.

**Background //** I have two tab-delimited files (both with 3 columns):

```
$ cat file1.txt
4481679 4481722 .
4481791 4481820 .
4481947 4482268 .

$ cat file2.txt
13368   -       366
13668   +       940
14016   -       270
```

**Desired output //** I want to *merge/append* the second column of file2.txt to file1.txt (output file has 4 columns):

```
$ cat file1.txt
4481679 4481722 .       -
4481791 4481820 .       +
4481947 4482268 .       -
```

**Attempts //**

```
   # Attempt1:
$ paste file1.txt <(cut -f2 file2.txt) >> file1.txt
   # Attempt2:
$ cut -f2 file2.txt | paste file1.txt - >> file1.txt
   # Attempt3:
$ paste file1.txt <(awk '{print $2}' file2.txt) >> file1.txt
```

After trying any of the above commands, the following error is returned:

```
paste: write error: No space left on device
paste: write error
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work without using `sponge` from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (i.e., using only things like `paste`, `cut`, `awk`, `sed`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut` and `paste` like so:

```
paste file1.txt <(cut -f2 file2.txt) > out_file.txt
```

Your error relates to your disk being full. Delete extra files to free up some space.